# No title on article page

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I have created a view which displays the 10 latest news items (articles). They show up fine in teaser format. When clicking on the full article there is no title displayed and I can't work out why. This is my node--article.tpl.php:

```
<div class="article">
  <div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <div class="postheader">
        <?php print $user_picture; ?>

        <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
        <?php if (!$page): ?>
        <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

        <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

        <?php if ($unpublished): ?>
            <div class="unpublished">
                <?php print t('Unpublished'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
        <div class="postinfo">
            <?php print $user_picture; ?> <!-- print the user picture, do not move if you want the picture displaying on the top -->
            <?php
                print t('!username • !date • !time',
                array('!username' => $name, '!date' => date( "d/m/y",$node->created), '!time' => date( "G:i",$node->created)));
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
        <?php
            // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
            hide($content['comments']);
            hide($content['links']);
            print render($content);
        ?>
        <div class="links">
            <?php print render($content['links']); ?>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
</div>
```

Also I should note that I'm very new to drupal and I don't know PHP very well.
If anyone could tell my why that would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Panels? Do you have a panel variant set for articles?

Comment: No, I'm not using panels.

Answer (score 2):

Your template is expecting that the node title will be displayed as the page title, which in controlled in the `page.tpl.php`. Either the title is printed, but not where you expect or you don't print the page titles at all.

Comment: I don't think it's printing the titles as it's not in the source of the page. How do I get it to print the title?

Comment: Something like `<h1 class="page-title"><?php print $title ?></h1>` should do the trick